# Active Directory - lost connetion when changing user password

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm facing problem with Active Directory. I'm trying to change user password, but getting ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1) in return.
I'm using ldap-tools from ubuntu shell

When adding user without password - everything works fine

Changing password using LDAPAdmin application for windows works good too.

Here's what I'm doing in order to achieve that:

```
ldapmodify -D {my adminuser} -H ldap://{my ldap host}:389 -w {admin password}

dn:: {user DN in base64}
changetype: modify
replace: unicodePwd
unicodePwd::{password encoded in base64}

modifying entry "{user DN in plain text
"
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Thanks from advance

### Edit

As additional info, LDAPadmin doesn't allow changing password, when connected without any encryption, so I'm connecting to it with GSS-API with SASL enabled, as shown below

[image: ldapadmin connection properties]

But somehow, when I try to use GSS-API from commandline, I'm getting this error:

```
ldapmodify -U {adminuser} -H ldap://{ldaphost}:389 -w {adminpass}
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000))
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `ldapmodify` and not something more user friendly, like PowerShell's [`Set-ADAccountPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adaccountpassword)?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunetally. The target is to make it in bash script, which will be triggered by oracle trigger, while creating new account in application. And whole environment of application itself is set on linux systems.